# Android 4.2 / Phonegap 2.3 FileSystem Access Problems

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I've been running through the FileSystem full example as noted here:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cor...

and am having a problem. I copied and pasted the code EXACTLY as noted in the link above in my test app.

Here's my problem:
When I run the app through Android emulator, it works just fine and gives me the following combo:
fileSystem.name : PERSISTENT
fileSystem.root.name : com.revdomain.appname

which is correct i believe.

HOWEVER, when I install and run on my Nexus10 tablet, I am getting '0' for fileSystem.root.name which leads me to believe that this is not working on this configuration? I am desperately in need of a solution as I have an app which needs to be able to write files to and access the fileSystem.

My configuration is as follows: using cordova 2.3 and trying to test this out on a Nexus10 tablet using Android 4.2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you see in "adb logcat"?